# Utility to rename those taskbar buttons in Windows XP and Windows 7

Tags: windows, taskbar

Does anyone know a utility that would rename taskbar buttons in Windows XP and Windows 7?

I've a bunch of programs open that all have the same name and I'd like to give each taskbar button its own name.

Comment: If you launch programs from `cmd` with the `start` command, you can specify an optional title, as in `start "My name" ProgName`. However, many programs set their own title while running (browsers show the title of the current page, file managers show the current directory, etc), so any title you set may get overwritten. The task-bar name is normally the same as the window title.

Comment: @AFH Cool trick but I want to specifically rename task-bar name to something else so I can quickly know which window is which (as they all have the same name).

Comment: Which programs are we talking about? If they are `cmd` instances, then as Snipe says below you can use the `TITLE` command within the scripts they are running. If they are explorer or browser instances, then the task-bar name will keep changing as the window title changes, as I said above. There are not that many other programs that are commonly run multiple times in parallel.

Comment: They are Win32 programs. They're designed by IBM for our university. It's not something you can download. They're for managing articles and authors. I keep 10 to 15 copies running sometimes as I need to cross reference the articles. But when all copies of the program say "For University of Washington by IBM". I use sticker notes below my LCD to keep track of which program manages which set of articles. I'd rather like to rename the program titles in the taskbar.

Comment: I can't improve on my previous suggestion of launching each instance with `start "IBM: document name" ProgramName "document name"`: the common header will quickly identify the program, while the document name will identify the instance (always with the proviso that the program doesn't update its title after launch). I have assumed here that you can pass the document name in the run string: if you can't, then you need the discipline of opening the correct document once the program is running. You could of course use a batch file **LaunchProg.cmd** containing `start "IBM: %1" ProgramName "%1"`.